i18n-js dynamic value return [object Object]
Here is my code in en.json:
"profile": {
    "spend": "spend more than $%{amount}",
}

in my component MemberCard.tsx :
{i18n.t('profile.spend', {amount: <Text style={{color: "red"}}>$100</Text>})}

However, the UI return spend more than $[object Object]
I am referencing the example on i18n-js Doc.
const i18n = new I18n({
  en: { greetings: "Hi, %{name}!" },
  "pt-BR": { greetings: "Olá, %{name}!" },
});

i18n.interpolate = (i18n, message, options) => {
  // ...
};

return <Text>{i18n.t("greetings", { name: <BoldText>John</BoldText> })}</Text>;

Is there any solution for styling the values using i18n-js?

You have to actually write the interpolation function so that it handles JSX, you can't just leave it as // ...

@GuyIncognito Thanks for your reply! I was thinking how does this function work. Is this function place in my i18n-js setting up file?

The codes I have added below belong to the i18n library, which I actively use for multi-language support. I hope this gives you an idea. If you have any questions regarding this method, I would be happy to answer them.
i18n.tsx File;
import i18n from "i18next";
import {initReactI18next} from "react-i18next";
import {getLocales} from "react-native-localize";

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
  lng: getLocales()[0].languageCode,
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        'ok': 'Ok',
        'cancel': 'Cancel',
      },
    },
    it: {
      translation: {
        'ok': 'Bene',
        'cancel': 'Annulla',
      },
    },
    ru: {
      translation: {
        'ok': 'Хорошо',
        'cancel': 'Отмена',
      },
    },
    es: {
      translation: {
        'ok': 'Bueno',
        'cancel': 'Cancelar',
      },
    },
    de: {
      translation: {
        'ok': 'Ok',
        'cancel': 'Absagen',
      },
    },
    tr: {
      translation: {
        'ok': 'Tamam',
        'cancel': 'İptal',
      },
    },
  },
});

export default i18n;

App.tsx File;
import {getLocales} from 'react-native-localize';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import i18n from './src/localize/i18n';

const LanguageKey = '@Language_Key';

// call the language page so that constant values ​​are loaded.
const initI18n = i18n;

export default function App() {
    
  const getData = async (key: string) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (value !== null) {
        if (key === LanguageKey) {
          // If there is a saved language value at startup, change the language.
          i18n.changeLanguage(value);
        }
        
      } else {
        if (key === LanguageKey) {
          // Since there is no language value registered initially, the system language is set.
          i18n.changeLanguage(getLocales()[0].languageCode);
        } 
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(LanguageKey);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>

    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

HomeScreen.tsx File;
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

function HomeScreen() {

  const {t} = useTranslation();

  return (
    <View>
       <Text>
          {t('ok')}
        </Text>
       <Text>
          {t('cancel')}
        </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

Settings.tsx File;
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
import {getLocales} from 'react-native-localize';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const LanguageKey = '@Language_Key';

import i18n from './src/localize/i18n';

function SettingsView() {
  const {t} = useTranslation();

  function AppLanguageView({navigation}: any) {
    function LanguageButton({
      languageCode,
      languageText,
      countryFlagCode,
    }: any) {
      function changeLanguage(language: any) {
        storeData(LanguageKey, language);
        i18n.changeLanguage(language);
      }

      return (
        <Pressable onPress={() => changeLanguage(languageCode)}>
          <View>
            <Text>{languageText}</Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
      );
    }

    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <LanguageButton
          languageCode="en"
          languageText={t('english')}
          countryFlagCode="US"
        />
        <LanguageButton
          languageCode="tr"
          languageText={t('turkish')}
          countryFlagCode="TR"
        />
        <LanguageButton
          languageCode="ru"
          languageText={t('russian')}
          countryFlagCode="RU"
        />
        <LanguageButton
          languageCode="es"
          languageText={t('spanish')}
          countryFlagCode="ES"
        />
        <LanguageButton
          languageCode="de"
          languageText={t('german')}
          countryFlagCode="DE"
        />
        <LanguageButton
          languageCode="it"
          languageText={t('italian')}
          countryFlagCode="IT"
        />
        <LanguageButton
          languageCode="fr"
          languageText={t('french')}
          countryFlagCode="FR"
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <AppLanguageView />
    </View>
  );
}

